# Firebase is not defined even after adding scripts

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using the code given below to send notification using Firebase Cloud Messaging. But I am getting error firebase is not defined.

I have also added the scripts in my index.html file.

```
    <script src="/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-app.js" async></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-analytics.js" async></script>
    <!-- Initialize Firebase -->
    <script src="/__/firebase/8.2.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/init.js" async></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/7.14.5/firebase-firestore.js" async></script>

    <script src="../submitBooking.js" async></script>
    <script async src="js/notification.js"></script>
```

why is this happening and how can I solve it.

Comment: Firstly, the versions of all the Firebase modules must all match. Right now, you have three different versions represented here, and version 7.x is in no way compatible with 8.x.  Secondly, you should include the specific code that doesn't work the way you expect, or at least a very specific error message.  We can't see where the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a config.js file or a place where the config file is located. There, firebase, db, etc will be defined. It should look something like this in your index file :

```
<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
</script>
```

Obviously there will be strings / integers inside the quotes but those are identifiable and editable firebase databases so I left it out. When you create a new firebase database using the realtime database or cloud firestorm, you should get an option to copy the config file. Just paste it like this in your index file and you should be good to go.